# HTML input textbox abnormal behaviour

Tags: php, html, css

[image]

I am using joomla template i created a custom form in it everything is fine but when i clicked any of the input field and move mouse out of that inputbox, it attain some unknown properties the border size increased by 2px as shown in last state "clicked and mouse out". I have checked hover CSS property but it doesn't work for me. How can i get rid of that issue ?
My CSS is

```
.userforminput{
border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 0;color: #333;height: 15px;padding:   2px;background: 0;margin: 0 2px 4px;max-width: 327px;
}
.userforminput:hover{

border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: input[type=text]:focus { put your styles here }

Comment: set input:focus{border:none} in you css

Comment: Is it a blue border? I get this by default when I click on an input.

Comment: not blue one. i am talking about the black 2px border

Comment: How about you set `input:focus{outline:0}` ?

Comment: which Joomla component you are using to build the form?

Answer (score 0):

In your css, add the following:

```
input {
    border:0;
    outline:none;
}
```